# Realtek wireless adapter not working after update to kernel 5.11.0-25

Tags: kernel, updates

I am facing networking issue when kernel updated on my 20.04 LTS from 5.8.0-63 to 5.11.0-25. All worked fine in 5.8.0-63.
After update, the wifi networking is not available at all.
I am running a VMWare installation with a tp-link wifi usb stick.

I tried steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347951/wireless-adapter-unclaimed-after-update-and-reboot/).
I did `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic`
and `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic`.

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` shows no output at all.

In 5.8.0-63 `lshw -c network` shows

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlxd037********
       serial: d0:37:**:**:**:**
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88x2bu driverversion=5.8.0-63-generic ip=192.168.2.122 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

and `lsmod` comes with

```
li@nux:~$ lsmod|grep 88
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_pcm               114688  3 snd_usb_audio,snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1371
88x2bu               2904064  0
cfg80211              778240  4 88x2bu,iwlwifi,mac80211,rtl8xxxu
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 vmwgfx
```

So, `88x2bu` is not loaded by cfg80211. What do I need to do?

Best, Holger

Comment: Please check whether this matches your problem:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.11/+bug/1939635

Comment: if I understand correctly, you see 88x2bu module listed in 5.8.0-63 but not in the new version 5.11.0-25. Have you checked if 88x2bu.ko file exists in the kernel module /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/. tree? How did you install or get the Realtek driver? Did you build yourself using dkms tool or run a command such as sudo apt install realtek-module-xxxx?

Comment: Understanding is (was) correct. But I did not do the other checks. I build and installed using dkms. Previous kernel updates went well - nothing to be done at all.

Answer (score 1):

I got a hint to use [RinCat](https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver) driver. I installed successfully according to the description (again compile & dkms). DONE.