# No Wifi Adapter after Nvidia update (Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia 460-470)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, nvidia, kernel

I am experiencing some wifi troubles, and would very much appreciate some advice for my situation.

I am currently running ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot.

I use a dual monitor setup, but this morning ubuntu could not detect the second monitor.
After finding some suggestions to update my Nvidia version, I ran :
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade -y` This changed my Nvidia driver from version 460 to 470. Also changed my kernel from 5.13.0-27-generic to 5.13.0-28-generic.
Here's some of my system details:
`lshw - short`

```
H/W path              Device        Class       Description
===========================================================
                                    system      Computer
/0                                  bus         Motherboard
/0/0                                memory      130GiB System memory
/0/1                                processor   AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor
/0/100                              bridge      Starship/Matisse Root Complex
/0/100/0.2                          generic     Starship/Matisse IOMMU
/0/100/1.1                          bridge      Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.1/0                        storage     NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
/0/100/1.1/0/0        /dev/nvme0    storage     Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
/0/100/1.1/0/0/1      /dev/nvme0n1  disk        NVMe namespace
/0/100/1.2                          bridge      Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0                        bridge      Matisse Switch Upstream
/0/100/1.2/0/0                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0                    storage     NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0/0    /dev/nvme1    storage     Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
/0/100/1.2/0/0/0/0/1  /dev/nvme1n1  disk        NVMe namespace
/0/100/1.2/0/1                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0                    storage     NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/0    /dev/nvme2    storage     Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
/0/100/1.2/0/1/0/0/1  /dev/nvme2n1  disk        NVMe namespace
/0/100/1.2/0/5                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/5/0                    network     RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/6                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/6/0                    network     Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1.2/0/8                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0                    generic     Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.1                  bus         Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/8/0.3                  bus         Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/1.2/0/9                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/9/0                    storage     FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1.2/0/a                      bridge      Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
/0/100/1.2/0/a/0                    storage     FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/3.1                          bridge      Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
/0/100/3.1/0                        display     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/3.1/0.1                      multimedia  NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/7.1                          bridge      Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/7.1/0                        generic     Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
/0/100/8.1                          bridge      Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
/0/100/8.1/0                        generic     Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
/0/100/8.1/0.3                      bus         Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
/0/100/8.1/0.4                      multimedia  Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
/0/100/14                           bus         FCH SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.3                         bridge      FCH LPC Bridge
/0/101                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/102                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/103                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/104                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/105                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/106                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/107                              bridge      Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
/0/108                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 0
/0/109                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 1
/0/10a                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 2
/0/10b                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 3
/0/10c                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 4
/0/10d                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 5
/0/10e                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 6
/0/10f                              bridge      Matisse Device 24: Function 7
/0/2                                system      PnP device PNP0c01
/0/3                                system      PnP device PNP0c02
/0/4                                system      PnP device PNP0b00
/0/5                                system      PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                                system      PnP device PNP0c02
```

After rebooting, the second monitor was detected, but I had lost all wifi functionality. I can reboot into an old kernel version and the wifi there still works.

`lshw -C Network` still detects the Wirless Interface:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network Controller
    product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
    Vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
    version: 1a
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33 MHz
    capabililties: cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:fc600000-fc603fff
```

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` reutrns

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

`rfkill list` returns nothing

Finally I have seen this post:
[Wireless adapter unclaimed after update and reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347951/wireless-adapter-unclaimed-after-update-and-reboot), however after switching to the kernel with wifi and running `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic` returns
`Package: 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic' has no installation candidate`.

`dpkg -l | grep linux`

```
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                  2.34-6ubuntu1.3                       amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  console-setup-linux                        1.194ubuntu3                          all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  libselinux1:amd64                          3.0-1build2                           amd64        SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libv4l-0:amd64                             1.18.0-2build1                        amd64        Collection of video4linux support libraries
ii  libv4lconvert0:amd64                       1.18.0-2build1                        amd64        Video4linux frame format conversion library
ii  linux-base                                 4.5ubuntu3.1                          all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                             1.187.12                              all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                    5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13                 amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic            5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04            5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-27           5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.13.0
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic              5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-28-generic              5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic               5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic               5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic               5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1+1                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic               5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic               5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                       5.4.0-97.110                          amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-5.13.0-27-generic            5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.13.0-28-generic            5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic             5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-44-generic             5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-45-generic             5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-48-generic             5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic             5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic      5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic       5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-44-generic       5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-45-generic       5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic       5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic       5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-43-generic  5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-43
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-44-generic  5.8.0-44.50~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-44
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic  5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1+1                 amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-45
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-48-generic  5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-48
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-53-generic  5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-53
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-28-generic 5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04 5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+1                amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-470 for the generic-hwe-20.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.8.0-53-generic  5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-53 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-28-generic 5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+1                amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-28-generic  5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1+1                amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.13.0-28-generic
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.8.0-53-generic   5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.8.0-53-generic
ii  linux-sound-base                           1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  pptp-linux                                 1.10.0-1build1                        amd64        Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) Client
ii  syslinux                                   3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   amd64        collection of bootloaders (DOS FAT and NTFS bootloader)
ii  syslinux-common                            3:6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1-2   all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                            2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                  amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
ii  util-linux                                 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1                     amd64        miscellaneous system utilities
```

Thanks for any consideration.

Comment: Please see the duplicate, except you need linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi chili555, I have seen the duplicate and ran its suggested solution with your change. It returns with 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic' has no installation candidate. Any advice on what to do from here?

Comment: Did you start with: `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: yes, I switched to the previous stable kernel, ran `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic` which resulted in the output mentioned above

Comment: We know it exists: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish-updates/linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic In Software and Updates, are all of the sources, i.e. main, universe, rstricted and multiverse enabled? If you change anything, please try again; update and install.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your intuition got me back on track, some sources were disabled, so I needed to re-run some of the other commands mentioned in the post.