# Wireless adapter switched to unclaimed

Tags: wireless, 22.04

My wife's machine is running with livepatch enabled. Today, the wireless adapter switched to unclaimed after an update.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2.

I tried `sudo lshw -C network` and got the following:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84000000-8400ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 11
       bus info: usb@2:4.3
       logical name: enx00e04c680bd3
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:0b:d3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.68.113 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

`sudo dmesg | grep 8821`:

```
[70006.427752] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[70006.428760] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[70006.428775] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[81851.972000] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[81851.973041] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[81851.973121] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[90848.444827] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[90848.445824] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[90848.445835] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[93541.235795] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[93541.236835] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[93541.236902] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[98937.036258] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[98937.037168] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[98937.037183] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
```

Unfortunately, dkms status was not as helpful:

`sudo dkms --status`

```
Error!  Unknown option: --status
Usage: /usr/sbin/dkms [action] [options]
  [action]  = { add | remove | build | install | uninstall | match | autoinstall | mkdriverdisk |
                mktarball | ldtarball | mkrpm | mkkmp | mkdeb | mkdsc | mkbmdeb | status }
  [options] = [-m module] [-v module-version] [-k kernel-version] [-a arch]
              [-d distro] [-c dkms.conf-location] [-q] [--force] [--force-version-override] [--all]
              [--templatekernel=kernel] [--directive='cli-directive=cli-value']
              [--config=kernel-.config-location] [--archive=tarball-location]
              [--kernelsourcedir=source-location] [--no-prepare-kernel] [--no-initrd]
              [--binaries-only] [--source-only] [-r release (SuSE)] [--verbose]
              [--size] [--spec=specfile] [--media=floppy|iso|tar] [--legacy-postinst=0|1]
              [--no-depmod] [-j number] [--version]
```

Comment: It's `dkms status` correct.

Comment: I did that, it got deleted by a mod. It had no response Here it is:
$sudo dkms status
$ sudo dkms --status

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem intermittently on my dual-boot PC (with Windows). Turned out it was not an install problem but something to do with Windows incomplete shutdown: https://askubuntu.com/a/1470080/1749726 worked for me.